# time delay when saving rows to Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I've built a simple trivia game that runs on iOS 5.1, 6.0, and 6.1.  I use Core Data, and I have these two objects:

```
@interface Category : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * category;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * difficulty;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *questions;
@end
```

and

```
@interface Question : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * disabled;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * displayTypeEasy;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * displayTypeHard;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * displayTypeMedium;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * questionID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Category *category;
@end
```

The idea is that each question has exactly one category (say, Entertainment or Sports).  The Category-Question relationship is one-to-many; in my sample data, there are 3 Categories and 20 Questions.

I have a Settings window that lets a user change which category they want to play and/or change the difficulty level of a given category (i.e. in this window, changes are made to the Category objects).  When a user presses OK, this code is executed:

```
- (IBAction)okPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSError * error;
    BOOL wasSaveSuccessful = [[Constants database].managedObjectContext save:&error];
    NSLog(@"wasSaveSuccessful:%@   areChangesPending:%@", wasSaveSuccessful ? @"YES" : @"NO",
          [[Constants database].managedObjectContext hasChanges] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}
```

BTW: "[Constants database]" is a UIManagedDocument that represents my persistent store.  Admittedly, this may not be the best way to keep this around, but I don't believe it's the source of my problem.

Next, the user can press a New Game button.  This fetch is then executed:

```
- (void) loadBatchOfQuestions
{
    if ([self.questionBatch count] == 0) { // self.questionBatch is an NSMutableArray
        // TEST #1
        for (Category * c in [[Category allCategories] objectEnumerator])
            NSLog(@"category:%@   difficulty:%d", c.category, [c.difficulty integerValue]);

        // TEST #2
        Question * q1 = [Question queryQuestionWithQuestionID:50150];
        NSLog(@"q1 difficulty:%d", [q1.category.difficulty integerValue]);

        NSFetchRequest * request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Question"];
        request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                             @"(disabled == NO)"
                             @"AND (questionID > %ld)"
                             @"AND (((category.difficulty == %i) AND (displayTypeEasy != NULL))"
                             @" OR ((category.difficulty == %i) AND (displayTypeMedium != NULL))"
                             @" OR ((category.difficulty == %i) AND (displayTypeHard != NULL)))",
                             MAX_QUESTIONID_FOR_TEST_QUESTIONS,
                             DIFFICULTY_EASY, DIFFICULTY_MEDIUM, DIFFICULTY_HARD];

        NSError * error;
        [self.questionBatch addObjectsFromArray:[[Constants database].managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]];
}
```

Here's the problem: If, after pressing OK and leaving the settings window, I wait ~10 seconds before pressing New Game, everything works great; the fetch in loadBatchOfQuestions returns the right rows, based upon the current Category data.  If, however, I immediately press New Game after closing the settings window, I see the old data (i.e. I query the wrong questions).

For the NSLog statements I added above:

- in okPressed, I always see wasSaveSuccessful=YES and areChangesPending=NO (as I would expect)
- for TEST #1 in loadBatchOfQuestions, I fetch all the Category rows (3, in this case) and have verified that I see the most current data
- for TEST #2 in loadBatchOfQuestions, I fetch one Question row to see if it shows the correct Category data; it does.

Nevertheless, the subsequent fetch returns the old data.

Here's what I *think* is happening:

- when I call save: in okPressed, it's actually writing the changes to an in-memory cache.  Those changes are then written to the Core Data persistent store asynchronously, over a period of 3-10 seconds.
- The fetches in TEST #1 and TEST #2 are pretty basic; they just fetch the object(s) with a simple predicate (no predicate in the case of TEST #1, since I want all rows, and @"questionID = %ld" in the case of TEST #2).  For these cases, the fetch can check the current data in the cache before retrieving data from the persistent store. (The documentation for NSManagedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest says "If an object in a context has been modified, a predicate is evaluated against its modified state, not against the current state in the persistent store. Therefore, if an object in a context has been modified such that it meets the fetch request’s criteria, the request retrieves it even if changes have not been saved to the store and the values in the store are such that it does not meet the criteria. Conversely, if an object in a context has been modified such that it does not match the fetch request, the fetch request will not retrieve it even if the version in the store does match.")
- However, my main predicate in loadBatchOfQuestions is complex enough that the fetch doesn't/can't look at the cache when evaluating it, so I see the old data instead.  But if I wait long enough, the persistent store will have been updated by the time this fetch is executed.

My questions:

- does my analysis make sense?  Or does anyone see some other bug/flaw in my code?
- if I'm correct, is there a way to work around this?  Maybe a call to a delegate method that tells me when the data is "really" saved to the persistent store?  Or maybe a property of the UIManagedDocument or NSManagedObjectContext that I need to set?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: I solved it with a brute force approach -- I requeried **all** questions and did the filtering in memory, i.e. I stopped relying on Core Data to handle the predicate.  Not a great solution, for sure.  But since I don't have a lot of data to query (at most 300 questions), this didn't seem to introduce any noticeable performance penalty.